# neo4j - how to separate or organize my nodes?

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to Neo4J, so I'm using Rest API to insert data. Like this:

```
POST http://site.co:7474/db/data/node {"type":"user",  "name":"mike"}
POST http://site.co:7474/db/data/node {"type":"admin", "name":"john"}
POST http://site.co:7474/db/data/node {"type":"photo", "url":"myfile.jpg"}
```

Is there any way to separate/organize my nodes by types and id's? Maybe folders or categories?

For example, in ElasticSearch I can separate by **index**, **types** and **define the ID** in URL, eg:

```
PUT http://site.co / objects / user  / mike
PUT http://site.co / objects / admin / john
PUT http://site.co / objects / photo / myfile
                     |index|  |type|  |obj_id|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at Neo4j's free online training course at http://www.neo4j.org/training, which introduces you to some of the basic concepts behind the platform. One of those basic concepts is a `label`, which can be used to classify nodes. A node can have many different labels. They are used to group nodes together and are useful for querying the relationships between certain groups.

For instance, let's consider the movie domain.

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(actor:Person)
```

Here we are looking for actors who acted in a movie. `(movie:Movie)` represents the group of nodes that have the label `Movie`. `(actor:Person)` represents the group of nodes that are people, which is a classifier for an actor.

Take a look at the REST api documentation to understand usage for labels: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-node-labels.html

Comment: Right you can use both labels (even multiple) but also connections to other nodes to categorize (tag) your nodes into groups or sets.